# Android custom searchview error when click button x

Tags: android, android-search

I have problem when click button x,  hint text is remove. when click icon search, it is show. how when click button x. hint text is show.
Code :

```
   /**
     * close keyboard and  clear test.
     */
    private OnClickListener onCloseListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            resetSearch();
        }
    };
  public void resetSearch(){
        setIconified(false);
        //Clear the text from EditText view
        mSearchEditText.setText("");
//        //Clear query
        setQuery("", false);
        //Collapse the action view
        onActionViewCollapsed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sucess when change :

```
    public void resetSearch(){
        setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        //Clear the text from EditText view
        mSearchEditText.setText("");
        clearFocus();
//        //Clear query
        setQuery("", false);
        //Collapse the action view
    }
```